# Integrate $\int_{\vert z \vert = 2}\frac{z+1}{z^2+1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Attempt**

I used partial fractions to write

$$\frac{z+1}{(z+i)(z-i)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}}{z+i}+\frac{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2}}{z-i}$$

And by residue this equals

$$2\pi i (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{2})=2\pi i.$$

is this correct?

Comment: You already asked a similar question recently. What makes you think this is not correct? In which part you aren't confident?

Comment: @Mark sorry I just wanna ensure I’m doing all the complex integrals correctly as I have a qualifier in it January 24.. I jus wanna know if my answer is correct

Comment: You can always [just check this yourself using Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cexp%28i*t%29%2B1%7D%7B4%5Cexp%282i*t%29%2B1%7D2i%5Cexp%28i*t%29dt).
$$\int_{\vert z \vert = 2}\frac{z+1}{z^2+1}dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2\exp(it)+1}{4\exp(2it)+1}2i\exp(it)dt = 2\pi i$$